# Extract Substring from a string variable that matches another variable using bash

Tags: string, bash, shell, variables, substring

`Var1=$(for i in I.am/First:Statement I.am/Second:Statement I.am/First:Sentence I.am/First:Line I.am/Second.Line I.am/Third:Line; do echo $i; done)`

`Var2=$(for j in First Second; do echo $j; done)`

Given the two above variables, I want to extract the substring from Var1 which matches the substrings of Var2

so, in the output, I would like

```
I.am/First:Statement
I.am/First:Sentence
I.am/First:Line 
I.am/Second:Statement
I.am/Second.Line
```

---

I have tried the following

```
for r in $Var2;
do
  if [ -z "${Var1##*$r*}" ]
    then
      echo "$r"
  fi
done
```

This prints only

```
First
Second
```

Any thoughts?
Thanks

Comment: Please add a shebang and then paste your script at http://www.shellcheck.net/ and try to implement the recommendations made there.

Comment: Well script is behaving as coded, you're saying for each "r" (First/Second) if the condition is true then print "r"...that's what it does.

Comment: So.. you want to use `grep`? Like `grep -f <(printf "%s\n" "$var2") <<<"$var1"`?

Comment: Thank you @Cyrus, that helped rectify the syntax errors

Comment: @KamilCuk - can you please explain how that code works?
```grep -f <(printf "%s\n" "$var2") <<<"$var1"```

Comment: @6yardcode grep takes an `-f` option that uses a file as a pattern, so if we give it a list of `$var2` it'll use every line of `$var2`. Instead of creating a file, we use [Process Substitution](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html) to use a command where bash expects a file. `printf "%s\n"` prints our variable (`$var2` replaces `%s`) then a newline. FInally, `<<<"$var1"` is a [Here String](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x17837.html), which is a way to pass a variable to a command that would normally read from stdin or a file.